# Create two new elements and append one after in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
var text = document.createTextNode('my text');

// I know this does not work but you know what I mean:
    var element = span + text;
    parentElement.appendChild(element);

    or with jQuert

    $('#aDiv').append(element);
```

How do I add the text node AFTER the span? and then I just add the span with the text to another element that exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `text` after `span`, like so

```
parentElement.appendChild(span);
parentElement.appendChild(text);
```

Or with jQuery

```
$(parentElement).append(span);
$(parentElement).append(text);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/fubere/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Or if your code structure forces you to have the text element inserted first (don't really see a use case so just saying) , you could use `parentElement.insertBefore(span, text);`

Comment: Thank you Alexander, but is this the only way to do it? Let say I have created 10 elements do I have to use appendChild() 10 times then?

Comment: @user3800924 in our case - answer yes, or use innerHTML like so http://jsbin.com/fubere/2/edit?html,js,output